# A oil drop is half immersed in water. What will be the direction of the force of surface tension on the drop?

Tags: surface-tension

Usually force of surface tension acts downwards , but in this problem , the direction is given upwards in my textbook. Am I missing a concept here , or the book is wrong? Please do help.

Comment: When does surface tension normally act downwards? How do you think [water striders](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gerridae) stay on the water's surface?

Comment: Surface tension is the force which holds up the oil drop. If it didn't point upwards, the oil drop would sink.

Comment: Yes , it does . Thank you very much sir.

Answer (score 0):

Surface tension is parallel to the surface.  But if you add up all the surface tension forces on the drop, the drop is being supported against gravity.  That is, the net force due to surface tension on the drop is upward.